# Why does TableViewRenderer Control Property change to null after Navigation Pop and Another Navigation Add

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The Control Property in this custom TableViewRenderer is set to null after the view that it is on is pushed onto the navigation stack once, then popped, and then pushed again. PerformScrolling() works the first time but no subsequent time after that because Control is null after pushing the same instance back onto the navigation stack.  Why is the Control property null but the TableView is visible in my app?  Is this a Xamarin bug?

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PropertyTableView),   typeof(iOSTableViewRenderer))]
namespace Project.iOS
{
public class iOSTableViewRenderer : TableViewRenderer
{
  ...

  void PerformScrolling()   
  {
       if (Control != null) //Control is null on second pushasync
       {
          try
          {
             if (SelectedRow != null && SelectedSection != null)
             {
                newcontentoffset = getRowOffset(SelectedRow, SelectedSection);
                Control.SetContentOffset(new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(0, newcontentoffset),  true);
                Control.LayoutIfNeeded();
             }

         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         throw ex;
        }

  }

  }
  }

...    

  void OnPropertyChanged(object c, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.PropertyName == "Scroll")
    {
        PerformScrolling();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you are asking as of now it does not make sense at all to me

Comment: Where you using `PerformScrolling()` method, you need to show more info about your problem.